# Find the least positive residue of 2009! (mod 2011).

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am not sure how to do this. I know that 2011 is prime, and from Wilson's Theorem I know that (2010!) = -1(mod 2011). But that doesn't help much and I am not sure how you could use Euler or Fermat's theorem.

Comment: What is $2010^{-1}$ viewed modulo $2011$?

Answer (score 2):

$$-1\equiv(2010)!\equiv(2009)!\cdot 2010\pmod{2011} $$  Now $$2010\equiv-1\pmod{2011}$$

Comment: I already figured out 2010 was congruent to -1(mod 2011)...I am attempting 2009!(mod 2011)

Comment: @user108711, so we have $$-1\equiv2009!(-1)\equiv{2011}$$

Comment: okay but that doesn't answer the question, it just is a different way to get -1 for (2010!)mod 2011. the answer should be 1 for (2009!)mod 2011. I am just trying to figure out a way to get there.

Comment: @user108711, so we have $$-1\equiv(2009)!(-1)\pmod {2011}\implies 1\equiv(2009)!\pmod {2011},$$ the cancellation of $-1$ from either sides is legal as $(-1,2011)=1$